# How to Get mysql_config_editor

Tags: mysql

I ran `sudo apt-get install mysql-client` and it installed correctly. Then I ran `mysql_config_editor print` and I got

```
mysql_config_editor: not found
```

`mysql_config_editor` does not show up in `/usr/bin` like I expect it to, and like it does on my other machine.

On the machine where it worked, `mysql --version` shows

```
mysql  Ver 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

On the machine where it doesn't work, `mysql --version` shows

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.45-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

How can I install a version of mysql that comes with `mysql_config_editor` or install the `mysql_config_editor` utility itself?

Comment: I solved this issue by using a Docker image from Dockerhub that has mysql pre-installed, but that doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

On MariaDB, as we have not a utility like mysql_config_editor to create ~/.login.cnf with obfuscated passwords, neither MariaDB reads it, one could degrade to ~/.my.cnf file with plain text:

```
[client] 
user=my_username
password=my_password
#port=mysql_port
#socket=my_socket
#database=my_default_dbname
```

And then change access modes:

```
chmod 600 ~/.my.conf
```

Now only you can read this plain text file.

This avoids you to type user and password on command line on debian os in an insecure way, readeable by ps command.

```
mysql
```

Ref. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-with-option-files/

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'm still confused as to why `sudo apt-get install mysql-client` installs this "MariaDB" thing instead of regular mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately MariaDB does not support this feature as explained here : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_config_editor-compatibility/

MariaDB is a fork of MySQL. So you can use its client to connect to a MySQL DB but it lacks the mysql_config_editor option.

Installing a MySQL client with mysql_config_editor is covered here : https://askubuntu.com/a/708606/943405
But I strongly advice you to uninstall the MariaDB client before and reinstall the full MySQL client to avoid troubles.

If you can't uninstall the MariaDB client then your solution is the best.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and relevant information. Unfortunately, `libmysqlclient-dev` has no installation candidate. https://askubuntu.com/a/1049909/953009 suggests using `default-libmysqlclient-dev`, but after installing that package on top of the base node docker image, the command `mysql` could not be found. It's weird to me that `sudo apt-get install mysql-client` would install this look-alike MariaDB thing instead of just installing actual mysql...